# Is there a clean way to forward template parameters to a templated function?

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, template-argument-deduction, function-templates

The following works

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template<typename A, typename B> double func1(B x, B y) 
{
    A a = 3.0f;
    return a + x + y;
}

template<typename A, typename B> double func2() 
{
    B x = 5.0;
    B y = 8.0;
    return func1<float>(x, y);
}

int main() 
{
    std::cout << func2<float, double>() << "\n";
}
```

---

However, what if I would like `func1` to be substituted with another similar function? One with the same number and type of arguments and template parameters. I tried `template<template<...` like below, and it didn't seem to work.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template<typename A, typename B> double func1(B x, B y) 
{
    A a = 3.0f;
    return a + x + y;
}

template<template <typename, typename> typename func, class A, class B>
double func2() 
{
    B x = 5.0;
    B y = 8.0;
    return func<A, B>(x, y);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << func2<func1, float, double>() << "\n";
}
```

It would be nice if a pattern like the one above worked.

---

Even better if `func`, could be partially templatized and still deduce from the type of the arguments like

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template<typename A, typename B> double func1(B x, B y)
{
    A a = 3.0f;
    return a + x + y;
}

template<template <typename, typename> typename func, class A, class B>
double func2()
{
    B x = 5.0;
    B y = 8.0;
    return func<A>(x, y);
}

int main() 
{
    std::cout << func2<func1, float, double>() << "\n";
}
```

Any ideas on how to get the 2nd snippet to work?

Could you do so with template deduction as well? Could c++20 concepts do magic here?

Comment: You can make `func1` a templated struct member function, and pass the struct (which is non-templated)  to `func2`.

Comment: @DietrichEpp got it to work with
```c++

#include <iostream>

struct MyStruct{
    template<typename A, typename B>
    double func1(B x, B y){
    A a = 3.0f;
    return a + x+ y;
    } 
};

template<typename Struct, typename A, typename B>
double func2(){
  B x = 5.0;
  B y = 8.0;
  Struct s;
  return s.template func1<A,B>(x,y);
}

int main(){
  MyStruct s;
  std::cout << func2<MyStruct, float,double>() << "\n";
}

```
Sorry for mess. I don't know the site to send one of those live links. Got any other possible simplifications?

Comment: Ah it looks like the template deduction also works! It's a little clunkier than I'd like but for a language that didn't start out with first class functions, nice enough!

Answer (score 2):

Function templates have some restrictions that class templates do not have. Consider that the type of `func1<A,B>` alone does not help you. You'd need the concrete function to call it. With a class template on the other hand, the type (an instantiation of the template) is all you need to know to use it.

Your 2nd code snippet works if you only change `func1` to be a functor, a class with `operator()`:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename A, typename B>
struct func1  {
    double operator()(B x, B y){
      A a = 3.0f;
      return a + x+ y;
    } 
};

template<template <typename, typename> typename func, class A, class B>
double func2(){
  B x = 5.0;
  B y = 8.0;
  return func<A,B>{}(x,y);
}

int main(){
  std::cout << func2<func1, float,double>() << "\n";
}
```

To deduce `B` from the parameters you can make `operator()` a template:

```
#include <iostream>


template <typename A>
struct func1  {
template<typename B>
double operator()(B x, B y){
  A a = 3.0f;
  return a + x+ y;
} 
};

template<template <typename> typename func, class A, class B>
double func2(){
  B x = 5.0;
  B y = 8.0;
  return func<A>{}(x,y);
}

int main(){
  std::cout << func2<func1, float,double>() << "\n";
}
```

Comment: In your last example, Is there a way to call func2 like func2<func1<float>, double> instead? that way calling func1 is similar to how it looks when forwarding through func2?

Comment: @M46f988b814 yes but then `func2`s first argument is a type not a template

Comment: It's says it can't infer B if I do that.

Comment: @M46f988b814 you can add a member alias to `func1` : `using type = B;` then in func2 `typename func::type x = 5.0;`

Comment: Oh wait nvm. I was blind. The typename change works just fine! Great!

Answer (score 2):

Alternative to the templated functors given in the other answers, one can also use a generic lambda, along with the [lambda's template support](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) from [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20).

```
// generic lambda
const auto func1 = [](auto x,auto y)
{
    decltype(x) a = 3.0f;
    return static_cast<double>(a + x + y);
};

template<typename Func, class A, class B>
double func2() {
    B x = 5.0;
    B y = 8.0;
    return Func{}.template operator()<A> (x, y);
    //          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^call of lambda like templated lambda!
}
```

This required the calling to be like:

```
std::cout << func2<decltype(func1), float, double>() << "\n";
           // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^passing type of the lambda
```

[See live demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/3nxMEe6Ge)

Comment: nice one. I think also using lambda in unevaluated context is C++20.

Answer (score 1):

> Even better if func, could be partially templatized and still deduce
> from the type of the arguments like

You can turn `func1` into an functor with a template `operator()`, and *partially* specify the template parameter through `.template operator()<A>`.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Fun1 {
  template<typename A, typename B>
  double operator()(B x, B y){
    A a = 3.0f;
    return a + x + y;
  }
};

template<typename Func, class A, class B>
double func2(){
  B x = 5.0;
  B y = 8.0;
  return Func{}.template operator()<A>(x, y);
}

int main(){
  std::cout << func2<Fun1, float, double>() << "\n";
}
```